# Unable to get IPython Notebook's url in WebBrowser

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser to display the webpages in a Windows Forms application. The Url i'm trying to display is the IPython Notebook which is,

```
http://localhost:8888/tree
```

and i'm able to achieve this using the below code,

```
this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost:8888/", false)
```

Now in this page when I click on the New->Python2 to create a new notebook, it generates a new url which is like,

```
http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
```

My requirement is to get this new Url in the WindowsForms application. I've tried the events Navigating, Navigated and I get the new url as,

```
http://localhost:8888/tree#
```

And I'm not able to get the right url. Any Suggestions on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to overcome this problem by editing the Javascript files in the IPython package. You can find the javascript file at the Ipython installed path,

```
IPython\html\static\tree\js\newnotebook.js
```

In newnotebook.js edit this line of code

```
var w = window.open(undefined, IPython._target);
```

and add '_self' in order to open the new url in the same window.

```
var w = window.open('', "_self");
```

Now I am able to get the url of the page using WebBrowser.Navigated and Navigating methods.